# download report/invoice as pdf format using payday gemfile in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

My code is

```
class pdfController < ApplicationController
def index
  @posts = Post.all
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    send_data pdf.render, :filename => "report.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline"
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Now  the problem is, pdf file downloaded. But I am getting an empty file, there is no report in that downloaded file.
And the code`@posts = Post.all` Post is a table, I can get the data from Post to downloaded pdf file.

Comment: You just do `pdf = Prawn::Document.new`, instead you have to add some data to it. Otherwise it will of course generate an empty file. Do something like this: `pdf.text "Hello World"` or `@posts.each{ |post| pdf.text post.name }` to add data to pdf object and then render it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in this post: http://adamalbrecht.com/2014/01/14/generate-clean-testable-pdf-reports-in-rails-with-prawn/

You can inherit `Prawn::Document` class for an easy configuration of your table border color and font size.

```
class PdfReport < Prawn::Document

  # Often-Used Constants
  TABLE_ROW_COLORS = ["FFFFFF","DDDDDD"]
  TABLE_FONT_SIZE = 9
  TABLE_BORDER_STYLE = :grid

  def initialize(default_prawn_options={})
    super(default_prawn_options)
    font_size 10
  end

  def header(title=nil)
    text "My Awesome Invoice!!", size: 18, style: :bold, align: :center
    if title
      text title, size: 14, style: :bold_italic, align: :center
    end
  end

  def footer
    # ...
  end

  # ... More helpers
end
```

Now, the above class is handful to use at other places by inheriting to some other classes, for example: posts reports, comments reports, etc. For your posts reports, We could do something like this:

```
class PostSummaryReportPdf < PdfReport
  TABLE_WIDTHS = [20, 100, 30, 60]
  TABLE_HEADERS = ["ID", "Name", "Date", "User"]

  def initialize(posts=[])
    super()
    @posts = posts

    header "Posts' Invoice Summary Report"
    display_event_table
    footer
  end

  private

  def display_event_table
    if table_data.empty?
      text "No Events Found"
    else
      table table_data,
      headers: TABLE_HEADERS,
      column_widths: TABLE_WIDTHS,
      row_colors: TABLE_ROW_COLORS,
      font_size: TABLE_FONT_SIZE
    end
  end

  def table_data
    @table_data ||= @posts.map { |p| [p.id, p.name, p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y"), p.created_by.try(:full_name)] }
  end

end
```

Everything is now up and ready to be used in DRY-way within your controllers.

```
class pdfController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = PostSummaryReportPdf.new(@posts)
        send_data pdf.render, :filename => "report.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that helps.